# Changing one JTable changes other JTable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, java-17

I am making a program in which I need many JTables. So for setting the font, column size etc. I am using this method:

```
public static void Enhance(JTable t){
        
       t.setRowHeight(70);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        t.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);

        t.setAlignmentX(JTable.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     
        t.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                   resizeColumnWidth(t);
                    
            }
        });


        int index = 0;
        t.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true);

        while (index < t.getColumnModel().getColumnCount()) {
            
            TableColumn a = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
            a.setMinWidth(130);
            a.setPreferredWidth(130);


        

            index++;

        }
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 27));
textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(dce);
for(int i =1 ; i<t.getColumnCount();i++){
    
    TableColumn sportColumn = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
            comboBox.setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,25));
            comboBox.addItem("Hulk- Maths");
            comboBox.addItem("THor - Computer");
            comboBox.addItem("Iron M- Geo");
            comboBox.addItem("Black P- History");
            comboBox.addItem("War M- Science");
            comboBox.addItem("Java  - Easy");
            comboBox.addItem("Custom");
            sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
            comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            
             Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                boolean editable = selectedItem instanceof String && ((String)selectedItem).equals("Custom");
                comboBox.setEditable(editable);
        }
            });
            

}
     
t.setShowGrid(true);
        t.setFont(new Font("Open Sans",Font.PLAIN,25));
        t.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 27));
        t.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
        t.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        t.setSelectionBackground(new Color(172, 208, 252));
        t.setRowHeight(50);
        t.setSelectionForeground(Color.black);
        t.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(23, 180, 252));
        t.setGridColor(Color.lightGray);
        t.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
        
     
        
        
        
    }
```

I am using this method like this:-

```
JTable t1 = new JTable(data1, title);//data is a String[][] Object and title is a String[] Object.

Enhance(t1);
```

Like this I have 4 more tables.

But the problem is when I make edits to `t1` , The JTable `t2` is also changing.

If I enter

```
"Java"
```

in the first cell of `t1`, the first cell of `t2` will also be

```
"Java"
```

How can I solve this so that edits made to `t1` is not visible in `t2`?

###### EDIT (Debugging details):

Even this code is also not working

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/*
 * Made By JFan
 */

/**
 *
 * @author JFan
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(1000,1000);
        f.setLayout(null);
        
        String[][] data = {
            
            {"","","","",""},
            {"","","","",""},
            {"","","","",""},
            {"","","","",""},{"","","","",""}
        };
        String[] t = {
          "1","2","3","4","5"  
        };
        JTable t1 = new JTable(data,t);
        JScrollPane j = new JScrollPane(t1);
        j.setBounds(0, 200, 500, 500);
        f.add(j);
        
         JTable t2 = new JTable(data,t);
        f.add(j);
        
     
        
        JButton  b = new JButton("Click");
        b.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           
                j.setViewportView(t2);
                
            }
        });
        
        f.add(b);
           f.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use the following steps to debug: 1) Create a JFrame with two tables each containing different data. 2) Then create an `enhance(...)` method that does nothing and retest. 3) Then change "enhance() logic to create a custom renderer for both tables and retest. 4) Then add a little more logic to the `enhance()` method and retest. 5) When it stops working then you know what you just changed and you can solve the problem or ask a specific question. The point is do incremental testing. It is easier to determine when your code stops working. Also, method names should NOT start with an upper case.

Comment: Sir I did like what you said. Then also it was not working. So I removed the `Enhance` method. Then also changing one `jtable` was changing other. I think the problem is because the data is same for all.

Comment: It doesn't matter is the data in the array is the same for each table. When you create a new JTable a new TableModel is created for each table. The issue is in the code you don't post. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. So your MRE would simply be a frame with two tables. Get this working first. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the MRE to see your described problem.

Comment: `You were NOT asked for your complete code`. You were asked for a `minimal` example. You need to first learn learn the basics of creating a table. As I stated it should be a frame with two tables. The class code will be about 20 lines of code. A few lines to create your data. A couple of lines to create the two tables. And a few more to create the frame. Learn the basics, then learn how to debug code you write. We can't help debug your application!

Comment: @camickr I have added a sample code which does not work.

Comment: Why would you vote to close your own question? I can't answer the question because it is closed because you took so long to post an MRE. Instead of creating the JTable with the "data Array", use the Array to create a `DefaultTableModel`. Then create the JTable with the model. Now the data from the Array will be copied to each model separately instead of being shared.

Comment: I posted the answer in my comment. What did you not understand? Don't expect people to write the code for you. If there is something you don't understand about the suggestion then ask a follow up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use:

```
JTable t2 = new JTable(data,t);
```

to create the JTable. This will create a simple TableModel using the Array as the storage for the data.

As you noticed, this Array is shared by all tables.

Instead use:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, t);
JTable t2 = new JTable( model );
```

Now the data from the Array will be copied to the DefaultTableModel.

Therefore each table has its own copy of the data.